# Is there any quick javascript library for working with collections/arrays?

Tags: javascript, collections, libraries

My question is slightly abstract.

I dunno is there any javascript library which allows to do such things:

1. Create a collection/array
2. Add an Object to that collection/array and mark it with any ID
3. Remove an Object from that collection/array by ID
4. Update an Object in that collection/array by ID
5. Get an Id from collection/array by passing an Object into it. (kinda search)

I apologize if my question is not as clear as you would like. But I really need help of experienced developers. Thanks.

One little remark. I need to do steps above as quick as possible, cuz I am trying to optimize for clients javascript-based project.

Comment: your question is clear, just misplaced.

Comment: Whats wrong with plain old javascript?  .pop(), .push()

Comment: I think you would be better off posting more of a concrete question, with the actual problem you're trying to solve.  Perhaps folks here would then be able to show you ways to solve the problem, and recommend a library if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a loot at http://underscorejs.org
I think for the ID part you should write some extra codes to handle it.